# External pocket SD drives constantly un mounting

Tags: ssd, unmounting, external

I have a persistent issue with certain 1TB external Seagate SD drives auto un mounting.
I need to constantly unplug and replug the USB connection for the drive to remount.
I have half a dozen of these drives but doesn't seem to happen with all of them.
This is in Windows 10.
Can anyone suggest a solution?
This is the model
https://www.amazon.ca/Seagate-Portable-External-Drive-STGX1000400/dp/B07CRG7BBH/?th=1

Comment: Could be many causes -- e.g., not enough power at USB socket. Try a problematic drive in a different port, or on a *powered* USB hub, or another PC to check.

Comment: Thanks. Good suggestions.